# how to fix Wrong key or corrupt data

Tags: postgresql

```
francois=# select quoi,login,pgp_sym_decrypt_bytea(password,'mykey') from passwd where quoi ilike '%tocken%' ;
ERREUR:  Wrong key or corrupt data
```

this is sudently happening was working find until now.

therefore

```
psql -c " select pgp_sym_decrypt(password,'somekey') from passwd where quoi ilike '%tocken%' ;"
           pgp_sym_decrypt            
--------------------------------------
 d728isperfectlyworkinge71ef
(1 ligne)
```

what did I missed ?? this is the same for all my password base.
calling pgp_sym_decrypt fails from inside psql but not as external call

full example :

```
    francois@zaphod:~$ psql
    psql (13.2 (Debian 13.2-1), serveur 11.11 (Debian 11.11-0+deb10u1))
    Saisissez « help » pour l'aide.
    
    francois=# select pgp_sym_decrypt_bytea(password,'xxxx') from passwd where quoi ilike '%tocken%' ;
    ERREUR:  Wrong key or corrupt data
    francois=# select pgp_sym_decrypt(password,'xxxx') from passwd where quoi ilike '%tocken%' ;
    ERREUR:  Wrong key or corrupt data
    francois=# \q
    francois@zaphod:~$ psql -c "select pgp_sym_decrypt(password,'xxxx') from passwd where quoi ilike '%tocken%' ;"
    ERREUR:  Wrong key or corrupt data
    francois@zaphod:~$ psql -c "select pgp_sym_decrypt_bytea(password,'xxxx') from passwd where quoi ilike '%tocken%' ;"
    ERREUR:  Wrong key or corrupt data
    francois@zaphod:~$ francois@zaphod:~$ psql -c "select quoi,login,pgp_sym_decrypt(password,'xxxxx') from passwd where quoi ilike '%tocken%' ;"
       quoi       |      login       |           pgp_sym_decrypt            
------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------
 xxxxxxxxx tocken | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx | d728d529-6be2-45f9-a7c2-126fa01e71ef
(1 ligne)

francois@zaphod:~$
```

seems to be random ...

Comment: 'goblinrieur' is the correct key, so it decrypts, and 'xxx' is a wrong key, so it refuses. Same goes for 'mykey' and 'somekey'. It's not possible from your question to understand what other results you expected and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from what you've posted, I spotted that you're using different *keys* in both calls.
So I pasted them below, alongside one another and it appears that you're calling completely different *functions* as well!

```
1. pgp_sym_decrypt_bytea ( password, 'mykey'   )
2. pgp_sym_decrypt       ( password, 'somekey' )
```

Oops?

However ...
Why are you *decrypting* passwords *at all*?

If someone were to get hold of your database and your keys, all of your users' passwords would be compromised.
Passwords should be stored as a [one-way] hashed value and comparisons should only be made against those hashed values.

Comment: no in fact it is the same & the same key & I've just copy/paste different examples from testing

Comment: @francoisP  Attention to details matter.  How are we supposed to know what you actually did if you are not accurately telling is what you actually did?

Comment: I can do no more than a screen shot as I did just above @jjanes

Comment: @francoisP Your screen shot shows it working with one password, and failing with a different one.

Comment: no I just forgot to replace it with neutral xxxxx